# Upgrade to Angular 1.6 breaks select dropdown

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-options, angular1.6

I have an app built using Angular 1.5 where the following code works just fine:

```
      <div class="select-wrapper">

        <select ng-model="myModel"
          ng-options="thing as thing for (thing, otherThing) in sortedThings">

          <option value="">MAKE SELECTION</option>

        </select>

        <i class="fa fa-angle-down" title="Select Arrow"></i>

      </div>
```

However, when I upgraded to Angular 1.6 this code no longer shows the default option in the select box (MAKE SELECTION).

Why did this happen and how to fix?

EDIT: What I want to see is, when I first load page, the dropdown should have 'MAKE SELECTION' already selected.

Comment: Works fine for me http://plnkr.co/edit/lohXDuULU979fTteyUCx?p=preview

Comment: I don't see it working for you. When I click on your plnkr I see the initally loaded option to be set to option B. I do not automatically see 'MAKE SELECTION' unless I click on it.

Comment: remove selectedOption in app.js in plunker , to see the default selected dropdown value

Comment: Ok but that fixed his code, not mine

Comment: https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/QxNwdV  please share your js code

Comment: It should work. Please create a [mcve] (Maybe even a working stack snippet) including the values of `sortedThings` and `myModal`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When setting the model to the default option it is important to use the value `undefined`. Setting the model to the empty string `""` wont work.

```js
angular.module('defaultSelectValue', [])
  .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.data = {
     sortedThings: {
       a: 'fred',
       b: 'narf',
     },
     selectedOption: undefined //This sets the default value of the select in the ui
     };
  
    $scope.s2 = { 
       selectedOption: ""   //setting to empty string won't work
    }
 }]);
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>
<body ng-app="defaultSelectValue" ng-controller="ExampleController">
    <select
      ng-options="key as key for (key, value) in data.sortedThings"
      ng-model="data.selectedOption">
      <option value="">MAKE SELECTION</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <tt>option = {{data.selectedOption}}</tt><br/>
    <hr>
      Empty string doesn't work<br>
    <select
          ng-options="key as key for (key, value) in data.sortedThings"
          ng-model="s2.selectedOption">
      <option value="">MAKE SELECTION</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <tt>option = {{s2.selectedOption}}</tt>
</body>
```

Comment: I think this change happened because of [GitHub: feat(select): support values of any type added with ngValue](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/f02b707b5e4a5ffd1e1a20d910754cfabfc19622).